# Data binding TextBox to string in code behind fails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm attempting to bind a string property to a TextBox's Text field in XAML. I am doing this in a UserControl. I've searched StackOverflow and the internet in general and found various related topics, some examples:

- [Binding objects defined in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705322/binding-objects-defined-in-code-behind)
- [WPF: simple TextBox data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725554/wpf-simple-textbox-data-binding)

I've followed the code in these examples as best as I can but the Input property does not appear to be binding to the TextBox. I've tried various different methods of setting up the DataContext, including from the code behind and it's still not working.

What is it that I'm missing, is this an issue because it's a UserControl?

The code in the `SearchInputTextBox_TextChanged` event is called but always outputs an empty string. If I put a `Debug.WriteLine` call in the Input set section nothing happens.

**The XAML file:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DatabaseViewerApp.View.SearchBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="70" d:DesignWidth="240"
             x:Name="Control"> 
   <Border Padding="5" Background="#303030">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Search" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="20px" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="SearchInputTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=Input}" Margin="0,5" FontSize="15px" TextChanged="SearchInputTextBox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**The C# file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DatabaseViewerApp.View
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for SearchBox.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class SearchBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private string input;

      public string Input
      {
         get { return input; }
         set
         {
            if (value != input)
            {
               input = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("Input");
            }
         }
      }

      public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
         {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
      }

      public SearchBox()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void SearchInputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         Debug.WriteLine(Input);
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not that it isn't working...  The issue is that you may not be testing it properly.  Your code works for me in a new WPF solution.  What you may be missing is that the Text binding gets updated when you leave the focus.  In contrast, the TextChanged event gets fired as soon as the text is input into the text box.

So, whats happening is that when the TextChanged event is fired, the binding hasn't yet been updated.  If you try putting a breakpoint in your property setter, then change some text in the text box, and move focus out of that control, you should see it get hit.

As an aside, there isn't much sense in binding your Text to a property in the code behind because the UI element can be accessed directly from there.

Comment: Fantastic thank you! I Googled from your advice and found this: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-update-source-trigger-property/, then added `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding of the Textbox and it works perfrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <TextBox Name="SearchInputTextBox" 
        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Input}" 
        Margin="0,5" FontSize="15px" TextChanged="SearchInputTextBox_TextChanged">
     </TextBox>
```