# Databinding not working on Avalondock window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, avalondock

I have a project with a Window Manager using AvalonDock.

Basically there is two Element : a `LayoutAnchorableItem` to show my different tool box (currently one, consisting of a Treeview) and a `LayoutItem` to show the document opened with the treeview (a custom control, with bindable parameters - in theory)

The ViewModel of the DockingManager hosts the `ObservableCollection` named `Panes` that will be the LayoutItems.

Things works "fine" if I don't try to bind the parameters in the XAML, and force the values like this

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
    <panes:PanesTemplateSelector>
        <panes:PanesTemplateSelector.ExchangeViewTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xchng:Exchange/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </panes:PanesTemplateSelector.ExchangeViewTemplate>
        <panes:PanesTemplateSelector.GraphViewTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <grph:Graph TickerCode="ILD" ExchangeCode="EPA"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </panes:PanesTemplateSelector.GraphViewTemplate>
    </panes:PanesTemplateSelector>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
```

`Exchange` is the toolbox and `Graph` is the LayoutItems.

The initial databinding for the docking manager is done like this :

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         AnchorablesSource="{Binding Tools}"
                         DocumentsSource="{Binding Panes}" 
                         ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}"
                         x:Name="dockManager">
```

Note that Pane is of type `GraphViewModel` which has two public parameters : `ExchangeCode` and `TickerCode`.

The thing is I want to bind the `TickerCode` and `ExchangeCode` to the Panes.TickerCode and Panes.ExchangeCode values.

So I tried this :

```
<grph:Graph TickerCode="{Binding TickerCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ExchangeCode="{Binding ExchangeCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But it does nothing : TickerCode and ExchangeCode in the custom control are equal to `""` contrary to when I force the values in the XAML.

Also the somewhat weird thing is that if I step in the code execution, `Panes` actually have values for TickerCode and ExchangeCode, they just don't bind. For instance, the code that actually create the pane is

```
public void AddGraph(string FullName, string ExchangeCode, string TickerCode)
    {
        var graphViewModel = new GraphViewModel(FullName, ExchangeCode, TickerCode);
        _panes.Add(graphViewModel);
        ActiveDocument = graphViewModel;

    }
```

Here, every step has both values. And let's imagine that I add 5 different panes, they are all with their correct ExchangeCode and TickerCode, but nothing is passed to the custom control.

If you need more info on my custom control that values are bound to, here is the code : [Passing parameters to custom control (databinding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816114/passing-parameters-to-custom-control-databinding).

Remark: As you see I didn't put much of my code, make request if you think it may help and I will add what's needed. Note that the global logic of the whole window manager is the same provided in the AvalonDock test app (AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp).

Comment: I guess there is a problem in the databinding methodology that I am using. If took out everything non related to my current problem and created some blank project with a MainWindow constitued of only the custom control Graph with a datacontext with only the two paramters and bound them to the custom control : same issue, though the parameters actually exist in the datacontext, but are not passed to the custom control. I will look there...

Answer (score 0):

For example, if I’ve got ChartView and ChartViewModel:
In MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager"
                         AnchorablesSource="{Binding Path=Anchorables}"
                         DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=Documents}"
                         ActiveContent="{Binding Path=ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}">

        <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
            <selfViewPane:PaneTemplateSelector>
                <selfViewPane:PaneTemplateSelector.ChartViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <selfViewDocument:ChartView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </selfViewPane:PaneTemplateSelector.ChartViewTemplate>
            </selfViewPane:PaneTemplateSelector>
        </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

        <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <selfViewPane:PaneStyleSelector>
                <selfViewPane:PaneStyleSelector.ChartViewStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>                                
                        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
                    </Style>
                </selfViewPane:PaneStyleSelector.ChartViewStyle>
            </selfViewPane:PaneStyleSelector>
        </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>

        <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
            <selfViewPane:LayoutInitializer />
        </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>

        <xcad:LayoutRoot>
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="ToolsPane" DockWidth="200">
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane />
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>                
    </xcad:DockingManager>
```

And:
In ChartViewModel I’ve got property ChartPlotModel:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the ChartPlotModel.
/// </summary>
public PlotModel ChartPlotModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.chartPlotModel;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.chartPlotModel != value)
        {
            this.chartPlotModel = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ChartPlotModel");
        }
    }
}
```

In ChartView I can bind:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Jofta.Analyzer.UI.Classes.View.Document.ChartView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding Path=IsBusy}">
        <Grid>
            <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding ChartPlotModel}" />
        </Grid>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>

</UserControl>
```

In this example I’m binding to PlotView from oxyplot, but I think, you can use this pattern. You’ve got GraphViewModel, GraphView and TickerCode and ExchangeCode.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this doesn't answer my question. I guess I didn't explain it clearly enough. What you do as far as I understand is to have a custom control in a Main Window and then inside this custom control to bind data. My aim is to bind data from MainWindow xaml to the custom control, in order to pass some parameters to the control, which will, in function of those parameters bind data to the xaml of the control (as a matter of fact, an oxyplot chart :) )

Comment: I’m sorry I didn’t answer your question. I’m not sure I can understand what exactly you need. In my example I have MVVM pattern. From object explorer tree view (LayoutAnchorableItem) I’m opening charts (LayoutItem).

Comment: Don't be sorry Jofta, it's perfectly fine and very nice to try to help :) I am trying to find some tutorial on databinding as general as possible right now, I guess I'd be able to adapt it after getting better at it.

Comment: O.K. if you find a solution please post it here …