# Data Context can´t find object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

im rather new to wpf and trying to code a minesweeper game as exercise. My problem is that i cant get the datacontext of my `Stackpanel` to find the object `row` unless i set the datacontext for the whole window to the `RowUpper` class as seen in the code below.
Tried it with the row object as field of `RowUpper` class or as normal object in the `MainWindow` class. I want to provide the textbox `ZeitAnzeigeTB` with the value of the `timeShown` field to be able to show a counter.

***MainWindow.xaml.cs:***

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RowUpper row = new RowUpper();
        }
        //some more code
}
```

***Mainwindow.xaml:***

```
<Window x:Class="MineSweeper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuizApp" 
        xmlns:minesweeper="clr-namespace:MineSweeper" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MineSweeper" Height="920" Width="920">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="900"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Stackpanel" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding row}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               
                //some more buttons and textboxes
                
                <TextBox x:Name="ZeitAnzeigeTB" TextAlignment="Right" DataContext="{Binding timeshown}" Width="389" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="70 0 0 0" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="True"/>
                //even more textboxes and buttons
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***RowUpper.cs:***

```
namespace MineSweeper
{
    public class RowUpper : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public static RowUpper row = new RowUpper();
        private int time = 0;
        public string timeshown
        {
            get
            {
                return timeshown;
            }

            set
            {
                timeshown = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("timeShown"));
            }
        }
        public static void ResetTimer()
        {   
            using Timer Timer = new(1000);
            Timer.Start();
            Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            time++;
            timeshown = time.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only bind onto properties of the current data context, `row` isn't even a member of `MainWindow`, it only exists inside the constructor, not before and not after the constructor. You're also not setting your `DataContext` anywhere, if you want to bind onto Properties of your code behind, you'll need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705354/9363973)

Comment: As a note `return timeshown;` from the getter of a `timeshown` property won't work. You need a backing field for the property.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. Got it working now due to your tips. Watched a whole pluralsight course about this but cant really wrap my head around it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
DataContext="{Binding row}"
```

would only work of there would be a public property `row`  in the *current* DataContext, which is apparently not the case.

Setting DataContexts like you do in XAML is not how data binding works.

In the most simple case, you would have this constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new RowUpper();
}
```

and bind properties of UI elements to properties of the RowUpper object in the current DataContext like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding timeshown}" .../>
```

For details about WPF data binding, start with the [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0) article on MS Docs.